# Angular 2: how to clean build?

Tags: angular, npm

I'm using a development setup suggested [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html). At some point I have decided to delete a typescript file (say, 'myfile.ts'). My app was re-compiled in a blink of an eye, but myfile.js and myfile.js.map were left behind, although apparently they aren't needed any more. How does one "clean and build" Angular 2 apps?

Comment: well you see you might want to take the problem the other way. The way I see it, you're not building anything, you're just transpiling ts to js in a dev environment. angular cli comes with a build mechanism on the other hand, that generates a proper output in a dist folder. This approach is very standard and is shared by other tools such as maven for java. Of course it means you'd have to use ng-cli in your project to get this feature immediately. But if you can't, I am 90% sure there's a way to obtain a similar feature using grunt and some js compression scripts.

Comment: If you scroll just a bit in the link you posted they give an example of how to clean old files after a build. Add that to your build script as the first thing to run and you are set

Comment: @Sebas most of the time you wont be satisfied with just transpiling ts to js. Yiu need to take html, css & ts and produce compiled files.

Comment: @misha130 : Er... I have read the page we both mentioned, and I have re-read it top to bottom once again now, but I didn't notice anything regarding "how to clean old files after a build". Would you mind posting a quote?

Comment: I meant "Delete non-essential files (optional)" but you can adjust it a little to be clean